# How do I pick up these lock picks?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Without getting into anything too spoilerific, I've made it to a point in the game that I am trying to find a tear in the Columbia Bank. Convieniently, I've also already found the code book I need for the encrypted message near the back of the bank, so the spoils are practically handed to me!

As I'm looting the stash, I noticed a lockpick's bag at the back of the desk.

[image: Lockpicks in the Vox stash]

I try to grab it, and nothing happens. I try to grab it from all sorts of angles until I give up and decide it's just part of the scenery. On my way back out, I discover another bag.

[image: Lockpicks on the way out]

Again, more lockpicks that I want so badly to shove in my pockets, but the game seems to prefer to taunt me with them as scenery. That would have been the end of it as I was planning on moving on, until Elizabeth opened her big mouth and pointed each of them out so I could go pick up those lockpicks!

[image: Lockpicks that glow!]

Obviously these picks are meant to be picked up after all! For some reason, I don't seem to be able to do so. Is the game bugged or perhaps some kind of evil, twisted trolling? **How do I pick up all those lockpicks?!**

Comment: Did she refer to the actual bag. She may be pointing out that there's a lockpick by the bag.

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks I have to think so. I've picked up bags like this before, usually containing 3-5 picks. I've also been all around this thing trying to pick up anything at all aiming at it. I'm thinking it's a bug, as since posting this question I've pushed further in and none of the lockpicks in this area can be picked up. Not even the individual ones.

Comment: Dang! Yeah, it's def a glitch then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**The game limits you to holding 30 lockpicks at once.** Elizabeth will still point them out to you. However, they won't have the "shimmer" effect of collectable items and you won't see the prompt to press a button to pick them up.

If you proceed further and use a lockpick, you should be able to backtrack and grab the ones that looked like scenery.

Comment: Ahhh... So there is a limit... That explains a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Why they give you three digits when you can only use two... Just makes things confusing!